# ActiveX control within Java applet

Tags: java, applet, activex

The client I'm working for requires an app communicating with a scanner and photo camera which returns a processed image to their Oracle Forms 10 application. Thing is I already have an ActiveX control doing just that and I would like to use  it instead of rewriting.

As I understand it, `Oracle Forms 10` will dynamically download a `Forms Client` (a `Java applet` which will run in a `JVM`, `Oracle` provides `JInitiator` for `Forms` benefits) to the end-user's browser, which will run for any `Forms` application. This applet will connect to the server's `Forms Runtime process` which mantains a connection to the DB on behalf of the user.

Can a `Java applet` call an `ActiveX` control and, if so, how? The `ActiveX` has GUI parts which it can not dispense of for the image processing and as I've read, keeping them in the `ActiveX` called by the applet cant' be done.

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752352/load-activex-object-in-applet) as relevant, but as novice in web, `JavaScript` I don't understand much of it. How do I call the `ActiveX` control from the `Java applet`?

Being restricted to IE is not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, since both Java applet and ActiveX can invoke JavaScript code.

Java <--> JavaScript <--> ActiveX

However, you may encounter reliability problem.

Another approach is that you use Java to access scanners directly with [Asprise Java Scanning and Image Capture](http://asprise.com/document-scanning-library/java-image-scanner-api-overview.html)

*Disclaimer: I an am employee of Asprise which offers the above mentioned product.*